Why is my SQL SELECT returning all NULL values from a valid JSON column?
I have a table in an SQL Server database with columns containing valid json data.
example of data in a field: [{"max": 0, "min": 0, "price": 1000}]
Column datatype is nvarchar(max).
Code:
Select json_value(odometer_surcharges, '$.price') AS price from postgres.warranty_terms
The problem is that it returns NULL values for every record.

Please do what explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

since you DIDN NOT proviced any data and/or table structure this is an example how to read json from column:
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null, rawjson nvarchar(2000) NULL)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('[{"max": 0, "min": 0, "price": 1000}]')
,(null)
,('[{"max": 10, "min": 1, "price": 2.30}]')

SELECT id, [Max], [min], price
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.rawjson) WITH ([max] int, [min] int, price decimal(8,3))


result:



id
MAX
MIN
price




1
0
0
1000.000


3
10
1
2.300



UPDATE
if you want to use Json_value (treat json as array):
SELECT JSON_VALUE(rawjson, '$[0].price') AS price from @t


Apologies.  I had more detail but got chided for having too much information.  For future reference what more information would be better.
Table with a column nvarchar(max) with this as a sample record content:  [{"max": 0, "min": 0, "price": 1000}]
I thought this code sample would indicate fields and table.
Select json_value(odometer_surcharges, '$.price') AS price from postgres.warranty_terms
where postgres.warranty_terms is the table name and the column name is odometer_surcharges.  The data I wish to extract is 'max', 'min' and 'price'

I am also uncertain why my SELECT statement only returns null values.

Are you referring to datatype?  I noted it in the primary post as nvarchar(max).

JSON_VALUE(rawjson, '$[0].price')  - will work, because there is an array
